# Magento Subtotal/VAT error with discount code applied - PayPal wrong breakdown of payment

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout, subtotal, discount

I am desperately hoping someone is able to assist with this error that seems to be occurring with our magento (version 1.6.2.0) checkout and applying a discount code. It isn't the easiest to explain so I have attached an image:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/760Bm.png

Thank you very much for your time.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

Problem here is that paypal considers discounts on item total excluding VAT and in magento discount is counted overall. As Magento is not passing VAT amount to paypal, paypal calculates it.

If you want solution how to rectify then do let me know.

Comment: i don't use paypal, but i have the same problem.